# How should i send / pass the two dimensional array to a function using static memory allocation?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Here in the code written below, when I am passing the two dimensional matrix( in this case it is `nMatrix[][]`) , and in the function i\I am storing that into a double pointer. Then a problem is being created in accepting the elements of the array.

If I perform the same task using dynamic memory allocation and I keep the function syntax same, then it works perfectly. I want to know the reason, if anyone can help I will be thankful to him/her.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int inputMatrix(int **matrix , int row, int column)
{
    int i, j, nonZero  = 0;
    printf("\n Enter the elements of the matrix : \n");
    for(i=0; i<row; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<column; j++)
        {
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            if(matrix[i][j]!=0)
                nonZero++;
        }
    }
    return nonZero;
}
int main()
{
    int nMatrix[10][10], sMatrix[10][3], nr, nc, i, j, ch, nonZero;

// input the matrix in normal form
                printf("\n Enter the number of rows : ");
                scanf("%d",& nr);
                printf("\n Enter the number of columns : ");
                scanf("%d",&nc);
                nonZero = inputMatrix(nMatrix,nr,nc);
return 0;
}
```

In eclipse it does not show an error, and in Code::Blocks it shows note which is

```
note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[10]’
```

Comment: Please don't tag c++ because it's a different language. `int **` and `int(*)[10]` are not the same.

Comment: okay, what i want to say is that int ** is going to store the address which was created in the main and sent while calling the function, so when i am trying to access those memory blocks which has already been created then why is there problem?

Comment: @iharob can you tell me why int (*)[10] will work, i mean how does that works.

Comment: It's because the first `int **` is a pointer to pointers while the second is an array of pointers, their memory layout is different. Just change the signature  from `int inputMatrix(int **matrix , int row, int column)` to `int inputMatrix(int matrix[10][10] , int row, int column)`. Also, always check the return value of `scanf()`, specially to read integers.

Comment: @iharob, thank you so much... even i have seen same syntax in some books, this works also but i have a doubt that:-  if i write int inputMatrix(int matrix[10][10] , int row, int column) , then the matrix[10][10] will become a local variable to that function and thus the changes will be only done to that local variable, but i want the changes to be done to that which is there in the main () function.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Try it. It'll work as expected.

Comment: "_In eclipse it does not show an error_" -- What are the compiler flags that you use?

Comment: Yes it will work, what you should not do is treat the argument as an array because it now becomes a poitner.

Comment: @CoolGuy This question is asked very often, if you remember any duplicate please close it!

Comment: @CoolGuy yes that is working perfectly, and i didn't know what does compiler flag means.

Comment: @iharob, if you find this question is asked often , then before closing this one, send me a link of that. so that i can take help from there.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay Did you see `-Wall` or `-Wextra` or at least `gcc filename.c` anywhere (maybe in an option in "preferences")?

Comment: And as an addition, Always keep in mind that **The name of an array gets converted (*decays*) into a pointer to its first element.**

Comment: @CoolGuy that is Linux GCC

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay If the question is closed because it's duplicate, it will redirect to the duplicate question so you and others can find the required help. Don't worry about that :)

Comment: What compiler do you use in eclipse? Isn't it GCC? FYI, GCC is available in many OSes and not only on Linux.